# PySpark- How to handle source data schema change

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I'm trying to use PySpark to read from Avro file into dataframe, do some transformations and write the dataframe out to HDFS as hive tables using the code below. The file format for the hive tables is parquet.

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").format("hive").insertInto("mytable")
#this write a partition every day. When re-run, it would overwrite that run day's partition
```

The problem is, when the source data has a schema change, like added a column, it will fail with an error saying: source file structure not match with existing table schema. How should I handle this case programmatically? Many thanks for your help.

Edited :I want the new schema changes to be reflected in target table. I'm looking for a programmatic way to do this.

Comment: Do you want new schema changes in target table or you want retain target table schema as is

Comment: @MohanaBC Thanks. I want the new schema changes in target table. Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to evolve the schema of the Parquet files. This can be achieved in your use case with [Schema Merging](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#schema-merging)

As per your requirement, the a new partition is created everyday and you are also applying the `overwrite` option which is really a suited option for schema evolution.

Since schema merging is a relatively expensive operation, and is not a necessity in most cases, we turned it off by default starting from 1.5.0. You may enable it by

- setting data source option `mergeSchema` to `true` when reading Parquet files
- setting the global SQL option `spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema` to `true`.

*Code from offical Spark Documentation*

```py
from pyspark.sql import Row

# spark is from the previous example.
# Create a simple DataFrame, stored into a partition directory
sc = spark.sparkContext

squaresDF = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(range(1, 6))
                                  .map(lambda i: Row(single=i, double=i ** 2)))
squaresDF.write.parquet("data/test_table/key=1")

# Create another DataFrame in a new partition directory,
# adding a new column and dropping an existing column
cubesDF = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(range(6, 11))
                                .map(lambda i: Row(single=i, triple=i ** 3)))
cubesDF.write.parquet("data/test_table/key=2")

# Read the partitioned table
mergedDF = spark.read.option("mergeSchema", "true").parquet("data/test_table")
mergedDF.printSchema()

# The final schema consists of all 3 columns in the Parquet files together
# with the partitioning column appeared in the partition directory paths.
# root
#  |-- double: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- single: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- triple: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- key: integer (nullable = true)
```

> Note: suggestion would be to not enable the setting at global level as its quite a heavy operation.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to query off the system tables. You can run a comparison on these to see what changes have occurred since your last run.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which Spark version you're using, if you're using Spark version >= 2.2, you can use `alter` in your Spark SQL statement. For you case it should be:

```
spark.sql("ALTER TABLE mytable add columns (col1 string, col2 timestamp)")
```

You can check this document for more information about Hive operation in Spark: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-alter-table.html#add-columns